# Suggestions for Querying Hierarchical Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to determine the most efficient way of performing the following query with Entity Frameworks (using C#, ASP.NET MVC, and SQL Server).

I have a hierarchical table of locations. The ParentLocationID column reference the parent location. For example, Unites States might be a parent location of Utah.

```
[Locations]
ID int
Title nvarchar(100)
ParentLocationID int
```

And then I have a table of activities, with a reference to the corresponding location.

```
[Activities]
ID int
Title nvarchar(100)
LocationID int
```

The query I want to perform is to find all the activities for a given location, including all the activities for "sub locations" of that location. (For example, if the location is the United States, I should include all activities for United States, Utah, Salt Lake City, California, etc.)

Using C# alone, I would write a recursive method to implement this. But I'm wondering if either EF or SQL Server provides support for this scenario that would not require numerous, separate queries. I'd love to hear some tips of how other people might approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Common Table Expressions(**CTE**):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx